# jquery onclick parameters

Tags: jquery, onclick

```
jquery_target_img =  $("img[onclick=\'f(this,true,\"foo\")\']");
```

```js
function f(obj, a, b) {

}
jquery_target_img = $("img[onclick=\'f(this,true,\"foo\")\']");
alert(jquery_target_img.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img onclick='f(this,true,\' foo\ ')' />
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgky09Lu/)

should return other than 0 I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

You wish to target an element based on its `onclick` attribute value...

The issue you have is about a bad quote usage. Look below!

```js
jquery_target_img = $("img[onclick='f(this,true,\"foo\")']");
alert(jquery_target_img.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img onclick='f(this,true,"foo")'>
```

**Notice that** your empty function `f(obj, a, b)` probably is the reason why people downvoted your question as "unclear what you ask".

Comment: does not work, copied your code, except that jsfiddle uses later ver. of jquery https://jsfiddle.net/7c8e7j7r/

Comment: It works within a `$(document).ready()` wrapper.... That is to make sure the DOM is parsed prior to the execution of the code. See your updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7c8e7j7r/1/)